# How I can send parameters with uft8 format to page using jquery?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, encoding, character-encoding

Please, look at this jquery code :

```
        $("#ImageButton1").click(function () {
        var url = "Goods.aspx?key=" + $("#<%= TextBoxSearch.ClientID %>").val();
        $("#iframeID").attr("src", url);
    });
```

It works but when I'm trying to enter in TextBoxSearch by other language at the other side in my page load of good.aspx I'll get parameters using Request.QueryString["key"] it gives me like this "?????? ???? ????".

That's interesting when I copy and paste text into TextBoxSearch at result it works good at the Goods.aspx Pageload event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

```
var url = "Goods.aspx?key=" + 
    encodeURIComponent($("#<%= TextBoxSearch.ClientID %>").val());
```